# Relation between motives and geometric Langlands

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives, geometric-langlands

When working over a number field (or a function field over a finite field), one predicts that the Langlands program is related to the theory of motives over this field. There are several ways I have seen this formulated:

1. Every motivic $L$-function should coincide with an automorphic $L$-function.
2. Using some Tannakian formalism, there should be a homomorphism from the Langlands group to the motivic Galois group, satisfying certain properties.
3. In some special cases, something like a Shimura variety (in the number field case) or a moduli space of shtukas (for function fields) should be related the motive via some sort of correspondence.

The last point is not a systematic prediction, but examples should be the parameterization of a modular elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, or the notion of higher modularity in https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.11149

My question is: Are any analogous relations between motives and automorphic objects expected to hold in geometric Langlands?

I do not know how to formulate points 2 and 3 in this setting (I suspect you can't, as we don't deal with Frobenius or non-derived categories of representations), but here is my attempt to formulate an analog of the first prediction

Let $X$ be a (smooth, connected) curve over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $K$ denote its function field. For an algebraic variety $A$ over $K$, we can consider the etale cohomology $H^i(A\times \overline{K}, \mathbb{C} )$. This is naturally endowed with an action of $\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$. Supposing ramification is not an issue for the moment, this defines a local system $E$ on $X$. I will say $A$ is automorphic if there is a Hecke Eigensheaf $\mathcal{F}$ with eigenvalue $E$.

Is this a good notion of automorphy of a variety in the geometric setting? Does knowing "automorphy" in this sense give us any new information about the variety as happens in number theory?

Comment: As far as I thought there should Hecke eigensheaf on Bun(G) for ANY "local system E on X".  I thought that is proved by Frenkel-Gaitsgory-Vilonen . So the first part should be true.

Comment: Yes, it is in the abstract: "The geometric Langlands conjecture states that to each irreducible rank n local system E on X one can attach a perverse sheaf on the moduli stack of rank n bundles on X (irreducible on each connected component), which is a Hecke eigensheaf with respect to E."  https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0012255

Comment: Probably one may ask whether ANY local system on X comes from some motive A->X ? That is opposite direction to "Every motivic L -function should coincide with an automorphic L - function"

Comment: @AlexanderChervov Yes, it's true that one can find a Hecke eigensheaf for any local system on X, but that is not what I'm asking. I am asking if knowing this existence gives us any extra information about the original motive when the local system comes from a motive.

In any case, Will Sawin's answer shows we can ask whether a motivic local system comes from a motivic eigensheaf, so this question of automorphy is not quite answered by the paper you link.

Comment: @AlexanderChervov I don't think your question is analogous to "Every motivic L -function should coincide with an automorphic L - function". Asking whether every local system comes from a motive A->X is more analogous to asking whether a particular Galois representation comes from a motive, there is nothing automorphic involved.

Comment: By the way, the question you ask seems fairly well studied, see: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.06120.pdf 
In particular, not every local system is motivic.

Comment: Thank you, that it is cool !

Comment: Concerning the pre-last paragraph: "Let X be a (smooth, connected)... ". About:  "for A over K " we get "local system E on X".  To get that local system - we just consider the direct image of trivial D-module/(=perverse-sheaf) from "A" to "X". Is it correct ? Or I am missing something ?

Comment: @AlexanderChervov If we have a variety A->X (using X instead of K), then the fundamental group of X naturally acts on the etale cohomology $H^i(A\times \overline{X})$. The action of this fundamental group is enough to define a local system on X. I do not know how to make your D-module definition work; you never make a choice of i, which we need because we want to attach the local system to the motive $h^i(A)$ rather than the variety $A$.

Comment: The cohomology dimension "i" always arises in the same way - $R^i \pi_*$, that is we consider the derived direct image. For example what are the cohomology themselves - these just direct images to the point: $M \to pt$. In the context of the geometric/motivic local system it is described in the paper you mention, see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435745/finiteness-for-motivic-local-systems 
So conceptually both things are the same, but technically their might be some differences, that is not so clear for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First note that the formulation of geometric Langlands (the eigensheaf part, not the full conjectured equivalence of categories) is that associated to a local system on $X$ there exists an eigensheaf on $\operatorname{Bun}_G(X)$ which is a perverse sheaf. Both the local system and eigensheaf are objects in the derived category of sheaves.

There are multiple variants of this statement depending on what (derived) category of sheaves one works in, e.g. $D$-modules, constructible $\mathbb Q$-sheaves, constructible $\mathbb Q_\ell$-sheaves.

There are multiple notions of the category of motives, but a key property they share is they admit "realization" maps from the category of motives to the category of sheaves.

Based on this it's relatively clear what a motivic analogue of the existence of eigensheaves in geometric Langlands should be: Given a motive over $X$ (specifically a motivic local system, in particular whose realization is a local system) there should be a (derived) motive over $\operatorname{Bun}_G(X)$ whose realization should be the Hecke eigensheaf. Since there is a [motivic version of geometric Satake](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.08322) one can demand this motive is itself an "eigenmotive" for the motivic Hecke action.

This property, of the existence of a motivic eigensheaf on $\operatorname{Bun}_G(X)$, is not really a property of the variety, but only a property of its motive.

To prove cases of this motivic statement, the obvious strategy to try is to take existing constructions of the Hecke eigensheaf and attempt to follow the same construction in the motivic world. For some constructions, like that of Frenkel, Gaitsgory, and Villonen, this seems viable: The construction is a sequence of simpler operations on sheaves such as Fourier transform and intermediate extension and one just has to make sure these operations make sense in a given category of motives. Other constructions, like that of Beilinson and Drinfeld, are specific to a given realization and do not have an obvious meaning in the category of motives.

The application of automorphy, in a geometric or motivic sense, to learning information about the original variety may be limited. The biggest application of automorphy in the classical setting is towards the holomorpy of $L$-functions associated to the variety. But this holomorphy is already known in the function field setting. The only analogue for local systems is that sufficiently high wedge powers vanish, which is obvious in each category. I believe in some categories of motives the vanishing of wedge powers is not known, but it is unlikely that automorphic methods will be the solution - rather one probably has to prove the vanishing first on the way to constructing eigensheaves, if that's possible at all.

I'm sure there is information one can draw from this but it will be of a less dramatic nature.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Any local version of that ?

Comment: Or, say, taking the curve to be generalized cusp f^{(n)}(x=0)=0 . Then Hitchin's D-modules can be written explicitly: det(d/d - L(z)) . So would it imply that there are some which are kind of "motivic" , the others not ? If so, how to characterize those which are motivic  ? Bethe ansatz conditions select those which do not have monodromy. But motivic should be different condition, seems to be.

Comment: @AlexanderChervov I don't understand almost anything in your second comment - I'm not familiar with generalized cusps, Hitchin's D-modules, or Bethe ansatz. The local geometric Langlands I am familiar with takes place on a punctured formal disc. Over an algebraically closed field, a Langlands parameter (= local system on the punctured formal disc) is motivic if and only if the eigenvalues of local monodromy are roots of unity.

Comment: Associated to a Langlands parameter there is a category with an action of the loop group, and if the Langlands parameter is motivic there should be a motivic analogue of that, i.e. a category with an action (by convolution) of the category of motivic sheaves on the loop group.

Comment: Thank you. So "motivic if and only if the eigenvalues of local monodromy are roots of unity".  GL(1), tame ramification, G-oper: (d/dz - C/z)f = 0 , f = z^C , so "C" kind of rational number - corresponds to motivic, well quite far from Bethe Ansatz...

Comment: PS "C" is something like "Langlands parameter of the representation". As far as I understand.  For GL(2) G-oper (= local system)  (d/dz)^2 + f(z)d/dz + g(z) , factorize it: (d/dz - C_1(z) ) (d/dz - C_2(z) ) . The functions "C_i(z)" are kind of Langlands parameters - like "highest weights" - but since it is loop group our "highest weights" will depend on "z". That is - Langlands correspondence:   representation of loop group <-> G-oper (=local systerm) is rather simple and explicit (in that case).

Comment: @AlexanderChervov With regards to tame ramification, I should have specified that the motivic case only includes tame ramification, since motives correspond to local systems in addition to $D$-modules so motivic $D$-modules should all participate in the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence, i.e. be regular and holonomic. So $d/dz-C/z$ with $C$ rational are indeed the only motivic ones for $GL(1)$.

Comment: @AlexanderChervov  To allow irregular singularities one should consider "exponential motives" and then the motivic ones will be the ones with solutions where $f = z^{C} e^{ g(z)}$ where $C$ is rational (and $g$ is a Laurent series in rational powers of $z$). In these cases the correspondence will go to a category of representations of the Kac-Moody Lie algebra at critical level with fixed central character and in this description there probably is not a nice characterization of which ones are "motivic" but it should be possible to write down at least one example of a motivic representation.

Comment: Thank you !  Is it expected that construction of "Given a motive over X
 (specifically a motivic local system, in particular whose realization is a local system) there should be a (derived) motive over BunG(X)" can be made directly out of "motive over X" ?  Or it is not the case - just both things should correspond to local systems on X and thus correspondence between them.  PS if something direct is expected - are there some explicit examples - how to take "manifold/motive over X" and get those "C" which are discussed above ?

Comment: PS  For example : consider "X" to be a bit singular cusp curve u^2=v^3 - which can be described as "C[z]  without z". (And smooth everything at infinity). One can take some "motive over X" to be something like unital subalgebra  M in C[z,y] - again a singular as manifold, but still.   The G-opers (local systems) over such  "X" are again explicit differential operators in "z"  - so for each subalgebra M in C[x,y] there should be some explicit differential operator attached, if I understand things correctly.

Comment: @AlexanderChervov Your two questions seem unrelated. For the motive, this should be doable at least in the case of $GL_2$. Given a motive arising from a (piece of the cohomology of) a map $f\colon Y\to X$, find an open subset $U$ of $\operatorname{Bun}_{GL_2}(X)$ on which the universal vector bundle can be written as an extension of two line bundles. The extension $L_1 \to V \to L_2$ to $0$ gives by Serre duality a linear form on $H^0(X, L_2 \otimes L_1^{-1}\otimes K_X)$.

Comment: Now consider inside $U \times Y^n$ the closed subset of points $(V,y_1,\dots, y_n)$ where $L_2 \otimes L_1^{-1} \otimes K_X$ admits a nonzero section on which the induced linear form vanishes whose divisor is $[f(x_1)]+\dots + [f(x_n)]$. This gives a family of varieties over $U$, and the relevant motive is a summand of its motive.

Comment: @AlexanderChervov For your second question, constructing $C$ is much simpler. This is the usual story of the Gauss-Manin question: To find the differential equation satisfied by the cohomology of a variety, write down an algebraic differential form (on $Y_x$ or some Cech covering of $Y_x$) integrate, differentiate with respect to $x$, and integrate by parts until you find a differential equation.

Comment: I again don't see what's going on with the cusp. Why do you think motives over $X$ should be such unital subalgebras? You want to take the Spec of that algebra (so you're assuming it contains $z^2$ and $z^3$)? Such motives should all be very similar to each other since they all are covered by $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb C[z,y]$ which has boring cohomology. For me where cuspidal curves show up is that $G$-bundles on the cuspidal curve are $G$-bundles on its desingularization with a level strucure, which correspond to local systems admitting certain (necessarily wild) singularities at the cusp.

Comment: Thanks again ! About the cusps - it is in part motivated by the Serre's book "Algebraic Groups and Class Fields", where he (following Lang) builds class field theory over F_q. UNramified coverings - clearly correspond to Jacobians, while to cover ramified story - the "generalized Jacobians" introduced which are exactly the "Jacobians" of the curve X which "cuspified up to orders "n_i" at points p_i" - that is simply that the local ring in that point is substituted by "C[z] without z,z^2,z^3, ....".
I guess you know that much better than me - just for the context.

Comment: So that story about the cusp curves - "C[z] without z" or "C[z] without z and z^2 " 
 or "C[z] without z and z^2, z^3 .....z^{n}" and so on. Allows to compute everything locally - BunG, Hitchin D-modules, G-oper - everything is very explicit and written in "z" coordinate . But still we can think about these explicit local objects in geometric terms. So it is kind of both local and global - meaning that - everything is computable locally in "z" but geometric intuition is preserved.

Comment: So if we take such X - "generalized cusp" = Spec ( C[z] without z,z^2, ...z^N). We can consider motives over it Y->X.  I just to play with "Y" the same story - make it explicit, but a bit non-trivial, for the price to be singular. So, may be I desribed something incorrectly - just wanna do the same Y=Spec( C[z, y] without some monomials z^ly^m]. We get explicit "Y", but non-trivial.  For any such "Y" we should have a local system on "X" - which for GL(2) is given by G-oper: d/dz^2 + f(z)d/dz + g(z).
So for each unital algebra C[z,y] with map C[z]->C[z,y] we should get some G-oper.

Comment: May be that G-oper is trivial or non-interesting. Thanks for Gauss-Manin argument, but with singular Y it might require some work, so may be there is way to directly guess : d/dz^2 + f(z)d/dz + g(z) from the combinatorics of  the fan defining Y.

Comment: @AlexanderChervov If you're following Serre, then you're definitely in the setting I mentioned in my last comment: The $G$-bundles or opers on the cuspidal curve should not correspond to motives on the cuspidal curve, but exponential motives on the smooth curve allowing certain singularities at the point lying over the cusp. The simplest exponential motive would just be the trivial motive twisted by $e^f$: For the ordinary cusp, $f$ is allowed to have a pole of order at most $1$ at the cusp point. Deleting $z,\dots z^n$ would allow a pole of order at most $n$.

Comment: Of course in this case the relevant differential equation is $d/dz - df$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/467554/10446 attempt to describe the question more clearly