# Any "motive"(-like) theory which can catch that cusp $y^2=x^3$ (and similar) are non-trivial?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, motives, motivic-cohomology

Consider cusp $y^2=x^3$ which can also be described as $k[z]~without~z$ , taking $x=z^3,y=z^2$.

Algebraically its $Spec$ is quite different from $k$. For example:
it has plenty non-trivial "line-bundles" over it - parametrized by ground field $k$ : just consider  $C[z]~with~linear~term~equals~az$, $a\in k$ parametrizes nontrivial modules. It is exactly what one should expect from general ground - it is deformation of the elliptic curve - line bundles on elliptic curve parametrized by itself - so in that degeneration we see that $k$ parametrizes the line bundles on cusp.

However it seems some cohomology theories would assign to cusp - trivial cohomoglogies. E.g. etale seems to be equal to singular one - which are same as for $k$ and so are trivial.  See "comparison theorem (étale cohomology) in nLab
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/comparison+theorem+%28%C3%A9tale+cohomology%29  ", https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334677/comparison-between-etale-and-singular-cohomology-for-a-singular-variety  (thanks for Denis Osipov explaining that).

**Question:** Is there any motive-like theory which would assign a non-trivial motive to cusp ?

**Queston 2:**
Similar question concerning generalized cusp curve: $k[z]~without~z,z^2,...,z^n$ and more generally consider a polynomial algebra $k[x_i]$ and drop some set of monomials $x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}...x_{i_n}$ for some set indices $i_k$.

**Motivation:**
See MO questions: [What d.o. $\sum_i f_i(z)\partial_z^i$ correspond to subalgebras $M$ in polynoms $C[x_i]$ being Langlands dual to motive of $Spec(M) \to X$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/467554/10446), which is on related to :
[Relation between motives and geometric Langlands](https://mathoverflow.net/q/467020/10446)

Comment: Here in Appendix 6: "cuspidal curve" the Hochchild homology are calculated and they are non-trivial for cusp. https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.08477